# I want to get string inside the third bracket []

Tags: mysql, string

I have a string like

```
"Email Request processed successfully Emails:[xyz.abc@qubee.com.bd][HostName 
 =WSRC-AFFILIATE-1, Host Address = 192.168.103.105]"
```

How can i get `"xyz.abc@qubee.com.bd"` in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is same you can do something as

```
mysql> select 
 substring_index(
     substring_index('"Email Request processed successfully Emails:[xyz.abc@qubee.com.bd][HostName = WSRC-AFFILIATE-1, Host Address = 192.168.103.105]"',
    'Emails:[',-1
     ),
']',1) as s ;


+----------------------+
| s                    |
+----------------------+
| xyz.abc@qubee.com.bd |
+----------------------+
```